# Inconsistency in James Stewart's Proof of the Quotient Rule in "Calculus: Concepts and Contexts"

Tags: calculus

I have been reviewing the proof of the quotient rule as presented in James Stewart's "Calculus: Concepts and Contexts" and I think there might be a typographical error involving the disappearance of $\Delta x$ in the limit expression of the derivative of a quotient. It appears that $\Delta x$ is omitted prematurely in the process of deriving the rule.

The book presents the expression for the $\Delta \frac{u}{v}$ as follows:

$$
\Delta\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) = \frac{u + \Delta u}{v + \Delta v} - \frac{u}{v} = \frac{(u + \Delta u)v - u(v + \Delta v)}{v(v + \Delta v)} = \frac{v\Delta u - u\Delta v}{v(v + \Delta v)}.
$$

This equation is then followed by:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{u}{v} \right) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{v\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} - u\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}}{v(v + \Delta v)}
$$

However, notice that the $\Delta x$ from the middle equation disappears from the denominator in the equation on the right, whereas it should be

$$
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{v \Delta u - u \Delta v}{\Delta x v(v + \Delta v)}
$$

From there, I am not sure how to arrive at the last term which should be $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{v\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} - u\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}}{v(v + \Delta v)}$.

Could someone help clarify this doubt? I have just started studying calculus not long ago.

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} = \frac{\frac{a}{c}}{b}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
 \frac{v \Delta u - u \Delta v}{\Delta x v(v + \Delta v)}
$$
is the same as
$$
\frac{v\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} - u\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}}{v(v + \Delta v)}
$$
To see this, just divide numerator and denominator of the fraction by $\Delta x$.

Comment: Indeed, you're right! I greatly appreciate your guidance and assistance in understanding this. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer, to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.